# Error bars function throwing up an 'error' and not showing all error bars

Tags: r

I have been trying to create a 'simple' bar chart using the data below. One column within this data is for the means and another is for SE.

I can get the figure to work just fine, up to when I try to add error bars. Two of the error bars do not show and I have the following error message

> 'Warning message:   zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so
> skipped
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv,
> handler) :   zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so
> skipped
>
> 2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
> zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped

I'm hoping someone can tell me how I'm going wrong with my code and how to add error bars to this figure.

```
data1 <- read.table(text="season    se  mean    intersource
Dryseason   2.9 28.5    Highgw
                    Dryseason   7   4   Lowgw
                    Dryseason   5.1 2.5 Midgw
                    Dryseason   13.4    37.9    Highrw
                    Dryseason   7.2 4.1 Lowrw
                    Dryseason   0.5 2.6 Midrw
                    Dryseason   17.9    33.6    Highsw
                    Dryseason   0.6 91.8    Lowsw
                    Dryseason   4.8 94.9    Midsw
                    Wetseason   1.7 1.7 Highgw
                    Wetseason   0.3 0.6 Lowgw
                    Wetseason   0.2 0.6 Midgw
                    Wetseason   5   95  Highrw
                    Wetseason   0.3 0.9 Lowrw
                    Wetseason   0.2 0.6 Midrw
                    Wetseason   0.6 0.2 Highsw
                    Wetseason   3.8 98.5    Lowsw
                    Wetseason   3.1 98.8    Midsw
                    ", header=T)
                    
data1intersourceHighgw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Highgw"),]
data1intersourceMidgw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Midgw"),]
data1intersourceLowgw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Lowgw"),]
data1intersourceHighrw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Highrw"),]
data1intersourceMidrw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Midrw"),]
data1intersourceLowrw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Lowrw"),]
data1intersourceHighsw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Highsw"),]
data1intersourceMidsw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Midsw"),]
data1intersourceLowsw <- data1[which(data1$intersource=="Lowsw"),]
data1_3   <- cbind(data1intersourceHighgw[,3], data1intersourceMidgw[,3], data1intersourceLowgw[,3],
                   data1intersourceHighrw[,3], data1intersourceMidrw[,3], data1intersourceLowrw[,3],
                   data1intersourceHighsw[,3], data1intersourceMidsw[,3], data1intersourceLowsw[,3])
colnames(data1_3) <- c("Highgw", "Midgw","Lowgw","Highrw","Midrw","Lowrw","Highsw","Midsw","Lowsw")
rownames(data1_3) <- data1intersourceMidgw$season
lower<-data1$mean-data1$se
upper<-data1$mean+data1$se


my.plot<-barplot(t(data1_3), beside=T, ylab="", 
        cex.names=0.8, cex.lab=1.3, cex.axis=1.3, ylim=c(0,120), col = gray.colors(9),las=1)
box(bty="l")
legend("topleft", c("Highgw", "Midgw","Lowgw","Highrw","Midrw","Lowrw","Highsw","Midsw","Lowsw"), 
       cex=1.0, pch=c(15), col = gray.colors(9))

arrows(my.plot, t(data1_3), my.plot, lower, angle=90,length=.1)

arrows(my.plot, t(data1_3), my.plot, upper, angle=90, length=.1)
```

Comment: It's just a warning, not an error. You're getting that because for your really short bars, the value of `lower` is 0. You can't have an arrow with no length so it just skips that and gives you a warning. You can safely ignore it, though you might want to consider a different method of computing error bars than just `+/- se`